# keyframes off in scrolling slideshow

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-animations, slideshow

I found code for a scrolling slideshow I want to use on my site, but it's designed for 6 images, and when I copied the code and replaced with my 14 images, only 6 images are scrolling.  I assume it has something to do with keyframes, but I don't know enough about them to modify.  I modified the width of the container id from 1000px to 500px.  Also, something funny is happening with images appearing underneath the scroll.  If someone can tell me how to get the 14 images to scroll and seamlessly, I'd be very grateful.  Thanks.

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: white;
}

.photobanner {
  height: 233px;
  width: 3550px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.first {
  -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
  animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes "bannermove" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div id="container">
    <!-- Each image is 480px by 270px -->
    <div class="photobanner">
      <img class="first" src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_blue.jpg" alt="blue" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_23rd_st.jpg" alt="23rd st" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_broken_guru.jpg" alt="broken guru" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_church_ave.jpg" alt="church ave" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_nose.jpg" alt="nose" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_pants.jpg" alt="pants" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_i_will_miss_you.jpg" alt="i will miss you" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_network_reality_all_stars.jpg" alt="network reality all stars" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_kline.jpg" alt="kline" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_queen.jpg" alt="queen" />
      <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_water.jpg" alt="water" /></div>
    <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_swirls.jpg" alt="swirls" />
    <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_robins_egg.jpg" alt="robins egg" />
    <img src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/scroll_ports.jpg" alt="ports" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your above code, it is clear that the calculations are mismatching so we need to adjust this, to suit the 14 images for your requirement.

First problem was the div with class `photobanner` was not the same height as the images, so I corrected the height to `270px`, same as that of the images. Also, by default images will have a small space between them, to fix this you need to set the parent these images with the below CSS Property(`font-size:0px`) and the space will be gone, since space between images is there in the question. I am adding the space between using margin (`margin-right:2px`).

```
.photobanner {
    height: 270px;
    width: max-content;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    font-size:0px;
}

img{
  margin-right:2px;
}
```

Each image has the dimensions. (width:480px, height: 270px)

So the div with class `photobanner` contains all the images together. Each image has a margin inbetween them. Which is around 4px.

So the calcuation will be.

```
total width = ( width of image * 14 ) + ( margin * 14 )
   6748     = (       480      * 14 ) + (   2    * 14 )
```

So we can set the width of the `photobanner` div to `6748px`.

Then finally we set the animations `margin-left`, the calculation is as follows.

The images each have a `margin` of around `2`, also we should stop the scrolling on the last image ending hitting the right side of the container. Thus the calcuation will be.

```
margin-right = ( width of image * 13 ) + ( margin * 14 )
    6268     = (       480      * 13 ) + (   2    * 14 )
```

Below is a working example of the code.

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>

Please feel free to make tweaks to the code as per your requirements.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Two questions:  the speed of the scroll seems to have picked up.  What controls the speed so I can slow it down a little?  Also, is it possible to have the last image scroll seamlessly into the first one when the loop has run?  There is currently a break there.  Thanks again.

Comment: @BartonLewis For the first question its easy, you just need to adjust the time of the animation. I am taking the css property (`animation: bannermove 60s linear infinite;`) change it to some 60s or more depending on your requirement, for the second question, To my knowledge I can't help you there, because I dont know how to fix the current version, I think you need to follow this tutorial [here](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/)